# Order list by occurance and alphabetical if tied

Tags: python, sorting

I am totally new to python and I already struggle with a fairly small task.

I have a wordlist, in which I want to count the (duplicate) words, show the top "n" words and in case of a tie, order them alphabetically.

For the first two parts I wrote this:

```
def count_words(s, n):

    # TODO: Count the number of occurences of each word in s
    wordlist = s.split()

    #Count words
    counts = Counter(wordlist)

    #Get top n words
    top_n = counts.most_common(n)

    return top_n
```

but for `print count_words("cat bat mat cat cat mat mat mat bat bat cat", 3)` it gives me `[('mat', 4), ('cat', 4), ('bat', 3)]`, but I need it to be `[('cat', 4), ('mat', 4), ('bat', 3)]`

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: *order them alphabetically.* and  *need it to be `[('cat', 4), ('mat', 4), ('bat', 3)]`* don't coincide. You meant `[('bat', 3), ('cat', 4), ('mat', 4)]` ?

Comment: No, only if tied. Since bat has only 3 appearances, it comes last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
top_n.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

right before the return. It sorts by the first element of the key, then, if there's a tie, by the second. Since it sorts from smallest to biggest, the first value is multiplied by -1.